# Convert collection of init to standard objects?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

As shown below, I am seeing `[init, init]` when I view a collection of objects in the console. In order to access the properties directly, I have to stringify each item and then parse them back to an object, which seems silly. Is there a better way to do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: And you've tried `dataItems[0].Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By copying the properties on the instance into a new object, eg `{ ...init }`, you'll have a new *plain* object that doesn't inherit from `Init.prototype`:

```js
// Look at results in browser console, not snippet console:

class Init {
  constructor() {
    this.item = 'item';
  }
}

// Your original situation:
const arrOfInits = [new Init(), new Init()];
console.log(arrOfInits);

// Assign all properties on instance to standard object:
const arrOfObjects = arrOfInits.map(init => ({ ...init }));
console.log(arrOfObjects);
```

Still, you should still be able to access properties on `init` instances without any special code:

```js
// Look at results in browser console, not snippet console:

class Init {
  constructor() {
    this.item = 'item';
  }
}

// Your original situation:
const arrOfInits = [new Init(), new Init()];
console.log(arrOfInits[0].item);
```